# If $W_t$ is a Wiener process, why is the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (W_{S_{i+1}} - W_{s_i})^2$ equal to $t$?

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

For a Wiener process $W_s$ and a partition $\{ S_0, S_1, \dots, S_n \}$ of $[0,t]$, I have been told that
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (W_{S_{i+1}} - W_{s_i})^2 = t
$$
I am aware that the above summation is the expression for the 'quadratic variation' of $W_t$, but I am not sure why this is equal to $t$?

Can anyone please tell me how this result is derived?

Comment: The sum is certainly **not** equal to $t$. You have to take the expectation on both sides...

Comment: In that case, is this answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2685851/215853) not contradicted, since nothing is said here about taking the expectation?

Comment: The linked answer is certainly not claiming what you are saying in your post. It is saying that you should take a limit, right?

Comment: I have modified my question accordingly. Hopefully, it now makes sense?

Comment: The question was asked and answered on Math.SE. Search for "quadratic variation Brownian".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I will adapt an answer of mine in another post to answer this question)
Let $\pi=\{s_0,\dots,s_n\}$ denote the partition, we assume also $s_0=0$, $s_n=t$.
We define $$S_\pi(W):=\sum_{i=1}^n(W{_{s_i}}-W_{s_{i-1}})^2.$$ 
We want to show that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_{\pi}=t\ \ \ \  \text {in}\ \ \ L^2(\Omega),$$
which means $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E[(S_\pi-t)^2]=0$ (where $\Omega$ denotes the measure space on which $W$ is defined).
Defining $Y_i:=(W_{s_{i}}-W_{s_{i-1}})^2-(s_i-s_{i-1})$ we can write $S_\pi-t=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$. We observe that the random variables $Y_1,...,Y_n$ are independent since each $Y_i$ is a function of $W_{s_{i}}-W_{s_{i-1}}$ and by the definition of Brownian motion its increments are independent. Moreover
$$E[Y_i]=E[(W_{s_{i}}-W_{s_{i-1}})^2]-(s_i-s_{i-1})=\text{Var}(W_{s_{i}}-W_{s_{i-1}})-(s_i-s_{i-1})=0.$$
Thus
$$E[(S_\pi-t)^2]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E[Y_i^2].$$
We know that the distribution of $W_{s_{i}}-W_{s_{i-1}}$ is $N(0,s_{i}-s_{i-1})$ thus the distribution of $$Z:=\frac{W_{s_{i}}-W_{s_{i-1}}}{\sqrt{s_{i}-s_{i-1}}}$$ is $N(0,1)$. (Z doesn't depend on $i$ because we are interested only in its distribution and for every $i$ it is a standard normal). Using this fact we write
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}E[Y_i^2]=\sum_{i=1}^n E[\ [(W_{s_{i}}-W_{s_{i-1}})^2-(s_{i}-s_{i-1})]^2\ ]=\\ \sum_{i=1}^n (s_{i}-s_{i-1})^2\  E[\ [\left( \frac{W_{s_{i}}-W_{s_{i-1}}}{\sqrt{s_i-s_{i-1}}}\right)^2-1]^2\ ]=\\ 
 \sum_{i=1}^n (s_{i}-s_{i-1})^2\  E[(Z^2-1)^2]=C\sum_{i=1}^n (s_{i}-s_{i-1})^2\leq \\ C \vert\vert\pi\vert\vert\sum_{i=1}^n s_{i}-s_{i-1}=Ct\vert\vert\pi\vert\vert,$$ where $C:=E[(Z^2-1)^2]$ is a constant and 
$\vert\vert\pi\vert\vert$ denotes the norm of the partition. Now if 
$n\rightarrow\infty$, then $\vert\vert\pi\vert\vert\rightarrow0$ and we have the result.